# add space between react-alice-carousel items?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, carousel

I tried to create a carousel with this module and I need autoWidth property for my carousel. and the problem is my items are stick to each other and they need some gap in between, but there is no property for such. I tried to change the class margin property on the module itself but no luck. how can I fix this?

```
const LatestHotels = () => {
  const items = [
    <CardPrimary
      title="Premium Hotel Plaza"
      description="Sed interdum metus at nisi tempor laoreet. Integer gravida orci
                a justo sodales."
      location="27th Brooklyn New York, USA"
      rating="4.1"
      price={105}
    />,
    <CardPrimary
      title="Premium Hotel Plaza"
      description="Sed interdum metus at nisi tempor laoreet. Integer gravida orci
                a justo sodales."
      location="27th Brooklyn New York, USA"
      rating="4.1"
      price={105}
    />,
   // truncated for simplicity
  ];

  return (
    <div className={LatestHotelsStyles.mainContainer}>
      <Header
        title="Popular Destination"
        subTitle="Explore some of the best tips from around the city from our partners and friends."
      />
      <AliceCarousel
        infinite
        mouseTracking
        items={items}
        autoPlay
        autoWidth
        disableDotsControls
        autoPlayInterval={4000}
        renderNextButton={() => {
          return (
            <div className={LatestHotelsStyles.carouselNextBtn}>{">"}</div>
          );
        }}
        renderPrevButton={() => {
          return (
            <div className={LatestHotelsStyles.carouselPrevBtn}>{"<"}</div>
          );
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

result:

[image]

what I expect to be:

[image]

Comment: Add a runnable example so we could see what we could do.

Answer (score 0):

One way that i could find its to add a vertical padding or margin to each item component, so that they have this space between the items, just have to make sure that the first and last element dont have that lateral padding/margin cause that would make the starting and finishing items position a little bit off

```
.space {
margin: 0 12px;
}

.space:last-child, .space:first-child {
margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is to add padding directly to image in the items list. You san specify what padding you need and this style will be applied directly to image before being rendered in the carousel.

```
const items = [
  <img className={`pl-2 pr-2`} src={award1} onDragStart={handleDragStart} role="presentation" />,
  <img className={`pl-2 pr-2`} src={award2} onDragStart={handleDragStart} role="presentation" />,
  <img className={`pl-2 pr-2`} src={award3} onDragStart={handleDragStart} role="presentation" />,
  <img className={`pl-2 pr-2`} src={award4} onDragStart={handleDragStart} role="presentation" />,
  <img className={`pl-2 pr-2`} src={award5} onDragStart={handleDragStart} role="presentation" />,
];
```